# Mono.Cecil AddInterfaceImplementation equivalent?

Tags: reflection, mono, code-generation, mono.cecil

I am working on Mono.Cecil codegen util, and I want to preform following operation:

```
Loop through types
If type contains X attribute:
- Add ITestInterface implementation (where ITestInterface has defined some methods)
```

```cs
// For reference

public interface ITestInterface
{
    void Something();
    int IntSomething();
}

// Expected result, if type contains X attribute:
// Before codegen:
[X]
public class CodeGenExample
{
}

// After codegen
[X]
public class CodeGenExample : ITestInterface
{
   public void Something()
   {
       // some stuff
   }

   public int IntSomething()
   {
       // do some stuff
       return 0;
   }
}
```

I have seen that .NET Reflection has a AddInterfaceImplementation method (https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.addinterfaceimplementation?view=net-5.0).

Is there a Mono.Cecil equivalent or a workaround for this & how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved by:

1. Iterating over all types defined in the assembly
2. Checking which types have the attribute applied to
3. Injecting the methods.

As an example you can do something like:

```
using System.Linq;
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;

namespace inject
{
    interface IMyInterface 
    {
        int Something();
    }

    class MarkerAttribute : Attribute {}

    [Marker]
    class Foo
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 1)
            {
                using var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
                var interfaceToImplement = a.MainModule.GetType("inject.IMyInterface");

                foreach(var t in a.MainModule.Types)
                {
                    if (t.HasCustomAttributes && t.CustomAttributes.Any(c => c.Constructor.DeclaringType.Name == "MarkerAttribute"))
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine($"Adding methods to : {t}");
                        
                        var something = new MethodDefinition("Something", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual, a.MainModule.TypeSystem.Int32);
                        something.Body = new Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody(something);
                        var il = something.Body.GetILProcessor();

                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 42);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                        t.Methods.Add(something);


                        // Add the interface.
                        t.Interfaces.Add(new InterfaceImplementation(interfaceToImplement));

                        var path  = typeof(Program).Assembly.Location + ".new";
                        a.Write(path);

                        System.Console.WriteLine($"Modified version written to {path}");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {           
                object f = new Foo();
                IMyInterface itf = (IMyInterface) f;
                System.Console.WriteLine($"Something() == {itf.Something()}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another potential solution is to have the methods implemented in an internal class and copying over their method bodies.

As a side note, these are 2 online tools you can use to explore/learn more about CIL, Mono.Cecil, C#:

1. [Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/)
2. [Cecilifier](https://cecilifier.me) (disclaimer: I'm the author of this one)

That being said if you can use C# 9.0 you may be able to leverage the new [Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#support-for-code-generators).

Comment: Additional question, this only adds a Something() method. But I’m gonna need to have a ITestInterface implementation, due to I would like to pass that class after codegen into, for example StaticTestInvoker(ITestInterface test).

Comment: Sorry.. completely overlooked the interface implementation bit. I've updated the answer to include that.